# How to export azure data factory from one account to another

Tags: azure-data-factory

i have two azure account with different subscriptions and i want to move azure factory from one account to another.Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: hi.does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

You could export the arm template of your ADF account and import it into other destination.Please refer to this document:[Continuous integration and delivery in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment).

[image]

You could [customize the parameters of ARM template](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-deployment#use-custom-parameters-with-the-resource-manager-template) to change the different subscription information.